# App is crashing when it comes to foreground

Tags: ios, crash

In my project I need to call many web service on a screen. It works fine. I am calling services and make them to sit into database respectively. And same working in background.

But the app crashes when we press Home button and come back to app. Means when app turns into foreground, progress bar is hanging untill data insert into database and again progress hud is working. So
I want progress hud should work even data is inserting or web service is getting called and my app should not crash even it comes to foreground.

Is there any way to get rid out of this?

Comment: Please update your question with a **symbolicated** stack trace of the thread that crashes.

Comment: And also update your question with the relevant code involved in the crash.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call your webservice in background queue and hide progress hud in main queue.

```
dispatch_async(
  dispatch_get_global_queue(
     DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  //webservice operations`
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){`
    //hide hud

    });});
```

Comment: How can you possibly post an answer when the OP has not provided any details about the issue?